# Can an app send an email without opening the email interface in Android?

Tags: java, android

Can an app send an email without opening the email interface? How?

Comment: You need to implement the email protocol by yourself and communicate to mail server directly thru sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Simple Answer:

Its pretty easy to write an SMTP client yourself. See a sample here:
http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/22/android-send-email-via-gmail-actually-via-smtp/

## Elaborate Answer:

If you want to write a full featured mail client supporting SMTP, POP, IMAP etc then you should look at the android mail client source code:[Email app source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Email.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/email/mail/transport/SmtpSender.java;h=8f72631f85c3602530624945d8e3e72565e324ce;hb=HEAD)

Comment: Thanks Mubix... above links are quite helped me

Comment: hey Thanks dear... I am able to make the app for mail. but it only worked for gmail. Isn't any way which give freedom to access any mail(like yahoo, rediff). can we use 2 or more smtp for them

Comment: @Gomzy It should work with any SMTP server. If the server does not use SMTP then you will have to set the port to 25 and remove the two `mail.smtp.socketFactory` properties.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 98% sure that they only way you can do this is to write your own SMTP client and point it at a SMTP server you have a valid account on (or is open for relay).  ie, you can't use the standard email app or gmail to do this.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is probably a few months too late for you Mubix, but maybe someone else can benefit from it. I've seen many people refer to [this tutorial](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android) which shows how to send an email when a button is clicked within your app.